# Place an Icon Object in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have instantiated several System.Drawing.Icon Objects. Note that these are created at runtime and are not stored and loaded from the file system. I would like to place these images in my WPF application.

However as I have discovered over the last few hours, it is not possible to simply add an object such as an system.drawing.image or icon directly to the canvas/stack panel, nor is it possible to set the source of a System.Windows.Controls.Image to an image or icon not stored within the file system (or so it seems to me).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me dynamically setting a WPF Image with bytes loaded from a bitmap that was either dynamically generated or loaded from disk:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Examples
{
    public class Util
    {
        private static void SetBitmap(Image imgDest, Bitmap bmpSource)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmpSource.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

                imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
            }

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            imgDest.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks yes I tried something similar earlier but got a "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." when trying "bmpSource.Save"

Comment: Got it Working, I had to add my Icons to an good old-fashioned System.Windows.Forms.ImageList() first